# Histogram by data count

Tags: python, histogram

I have 1000 data points which are all in the range of 2.5-3.5. How can I plot a histogram for the count of data by 0.1 intervals Like how many data falls in 2.5-2.6, how many in 2.6-2.7. 
The data is stored in dictionary

Comment: is your data in a `list` or a `pandas data Series`?

Comment: its in {}, is that called dictionary?

Comment: if its key value pair its a dictionary otherwise if values only its a set

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a `set` of values named `data` ,ie `data ={2.5,2.6,3.2.....}`

```
#create bins using list comprehension
bins = [x/10.0 for x in range(24,37,1)]
>>>bins
[2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6]
# create histogram using matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(data, bins=bins)
```